# How can I place .dmg files away from the desktop?

Tags: macos, dmg

Every time I install an app, I get a DMG file showing up on the desktop. It looks like this:

[image: Mounted DMGs]

How do I hide it on the desktop or keep them elsewhere to preserve the aesthetic?

When I <kbd>Control</kbd> + click on it, I don't see any way to hide it.

Also, when I do `ls -al` on the desktop, they never show up. Why is that?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted as new users might be confused as to how these things work.  +1 for putting it out there!

Comment: See also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399622/weird-files-on-my-desktop-after-installing-programs/399625#399625

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you're seeing is the *mounted* disk image,  you need to **eject** them.

These are no different than a USB disk or flash drive that you attach or a CD/DVD media that you load into a drive.  It will show up on your Desktop so you have an easy way to access them.  Once you're done installing them, you can simply right click and then select *Eject*.

For example, I double clicked a (random) DMG file (Western Digital macOS Apps) that was in a different directory (from my Desktop) and the mounted file shows up on the Desktop.  If you double click, you will see the contents (usually install scripts or the App to be copied to the /Applications folder).  When you're done, right click and select *Eject.*  Note, many newer apps (VirtualBox I know does this) will, as part of it's script eject and move the DMG to Trash for you.

[image]

If using Terminal, you can see them by listing the contents of `/Volumes`:

```
% ls /Volumes
```

You cannot delete the item; if you  drag it to the Trash, the trash icon will turn into the Eject Symbol.

[image: Eject Animation]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112211/discussion-on-answer-by-allan-how-to-place-dmg-files-away-from-desktop).

Answer (score 29):

If you want to *eject* the mounted DMG, please [see Allan's excellent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399904/150839) - or more simply do a [secondary click](https://osxdaily.com/2012/01/28/change-or-disable-the-secondary-click-in-mac-os-x/) on the DMG icon and select the `Eject` option.

However, if you want to keep the DMG mounted, but don't want it to appear on your desktop, you can do that too! Go to Finder → Preferences → General, and under "Show these items on the desktop:" uncheck "External disks".

Note that this will also cause USB keys and similar to not appear on the desktop; you can access them from the Sidebar in Finder.

[image: Finder Preferences]

Comment: Little note: I wrote this because the question said "My question is, how do I hide it on the desktop/*keep them elsewhere* to preserve the aesthetic?" (emphasis mine), so I thought they might want to know how to keep the disk mounted.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that this is the correct answer.

Comment: an ejection will unmount but that doesn't mean they were deleted. The .dmg files themselves will still be in (most likely) the Downloads folder in Finder

Comment: I’m reading this over @Seamus and the question is about the images left after installing an application.  @Allan’s answer is more correct because it addresses the problem presented by the OP.  Why would you keep these mounted after installing the app. This answer is good, too, because of additional info but you wouldn’t do this with install images.

Comment: I quote from the OP: `My question is, how do I hide it on the desktop/keep them elsewhere`. The ambiguity in that question seems quite small to  my reading.

Comment: @Seamus What people ask and what they want are not always necessarily the same thing, especially when they might be somewhat unfamiliar with the subject matter.

Comment: I agree with @8bittree.  The first line of of the question is “Every time I install an app” which means the user has the .dmg with the install files still open. When you’re done with it, there’s no reason to keep it open. I know from many years in support that the words they use is not really what they want or need and you have to be flexible when listening to the question. Most important not take the question so literal because sometimes the user doesn’t know the right words. If I was Allans manager, I would give him props for hearing what the customer really wanted.  :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I wrote this answer, and I still think Allan's is more likely to be what the asker wanted. I just wanted to address the other interpretation as well. No one answer has to be definitive!

Comment: It’s a great answer @wow, I just wanted to address Seamus.

Comment: It seems I'm in the company of clairvoyants. Can you guess what I want in asking this question?